# How to properly use cin.peek()

Tags: c++, struct, cin, peek

This function is supposed to read a fraction and place it in an array.  If the user enters '0' the function is supposed to exit.  I am trying to do this using the cin.peek() function but execution always goes into the if statement and doesn't allow the user to exit.

How should I properly code this (I am open to not using peek(), I thought it was the simplest way of doing it.)

Thanks!

```
void enterFrac(Fraction* fracs[], int& index)
    {
        int n, d;
        char c, slash;
        cout << "Enter fractions (end by entering a 0): ";
        c = cin.peek();

        if ( c != '0')
        {
            cin >> n >> slash >> d;
            Fraction* f = new Fraction();
            f->num = n;
            f->den = d;
            fracs[index] = f;
            index++;
        }
    }
```

This test of peek() works however:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  char c;
  int n;
  char str[256];

  cout << "Enter a number or a word: ";
  c=cin.peek();

  if ( (c >= '0') && (c <= '9') )
  {
    cin >> n;
    cout << "You have entered number " << n << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cin >> str;
    cout << " You have entered word " << str << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added a case where I can get peek() to work correctly, but I don't see what is causing the problem in my case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two issues with your use of `std::istream::peek()`:

1. This function access the next character and does **not** skip leading whitespace. You probably want to skip leading whitespace before determining what the next character is, e.g., using the manipulator `std::ws`: `(std::cin >> std::ws).peek()`.
2. The result from `std::istream::peek()` is not a `char`. Instead, it is an `std::char_traits<char>::int_type` (which is a fancy spelling of `int`). The result may, e.g., be `std::char_traits<char>::eof()` and if the value of `'0'` happens to be negative (I'm not aware of any platform where it is; however, e.g., the funny character from my name `'ü'` is a negative value on platforms where `char` is signed) you wouldn't get the correct result, either. That is, you normally compare the result of `std::istream::peek()` against the result of `std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type()`, i.e., you'd use something like this: `std::cin.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type('0')`

That said, your program doesn't check whether it could successfully read the nominator and the denominator, separated by a slash. You **always** want to verify that reading was successful, e.g., using something like

```
if ((std::cin >> nominator >> slash >> denominator) && slash == '/') {
    ...
}
```

Just for entertainment, you can create a manipulator for testing that a character is a slash, indeed:

```
std::istream& slash(std::istream& in) {
    if ((in >> std::ws).peek() != std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type('/')) {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return in;
}
```

This way, you'd encapsulate the test for slash. If you need to use this in multiple places this is quite handy.

Comment: This is really helpful information, but I am still left with the same problem, unless I didn't understand something in your explanation :).  When the user enters '0' execution enters the if statement.

Comment: I am pasting code (in the question) that works using peek(), but I can't figure out how to apply it in my use case.

Comment: Did you add skipping of whitespace, i.e., this little `std::ws` bit? I'd be prepared to bet that the character you see in the test is some sort of space, most likely a newline.

Comment: @Azzi I think you're falling into the very common trap of thinking that `cin >> anything` or `cin.peek()` reads the next character you type in. It doesn't, it reads the next unread character. As Dietmar says almost certainly after you typed a number you typed a newline. You read the number but you didn't read the newline, so that newline is what cin.peek() reads, even though you type a zero, the unread newline comes first. Add the whitespace extracter as Dietmar says.