# Separating numbers with characters

Tags: c++

So I want to get a list of numbers. So 1,2,3-5 would say 
1,2,3,4,5 
This is what I have coded thus far

```
cin>>num; 
vec.push_back(num);
if(cin.peek() == ',')
    cin.ignore();
```

How can I do the range part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/) to read more about cin.peek()

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501862/how-to-properly-use-cin-peek) for a great Stack Overflow question

[Click Here](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/streamio.html) I used this source to help you out.

I am assuming you are using namespace std
If you need more clarification comment and I will add more comments to my code.

```
 cin>>ws;       //eats up white spaces
 cout.flush(); 
    do          //loop to check every number
    {
        cin>>num1; 
        num_vec.push_back(num1);
        if(cin.peek() == ',')
        {
            cin.ignore();
        }
        else if(cin.peek() == '-')      
        {
            cin.ignore();
        //if it sees a dash it will ignore the dash
       // similar to what you did with your comma 
            cin>>num2;
            for(++num1; num1<=num2; num1++)
            {
                num_vec.push_back(num1);
      //keeps adding 1 to that range and pushing it back to vector 
            } 
                if(cin.peek() == ',')
                {
                    cin.ignore();
                }       
        }
    }while(cin.peek() != '\n');
```

Comment: what is cout.flush()?

Comment: @Alex flushes whatever is in the buffer